# Find Total Number of Repetetions of numbers in a file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with a string Global=x , where x is a number in between lines of text. I want to calculate the total number of repetitions of the number 'x' extracted from the string "Global=x". I don't want the number of occurrences of each 'x' printed.

For example, if the input file is like

```
Global=33333
Global=33333
Global=33334
Global=33335
Global=33336
Global=33337
Global=33337
Global=33337
```

the output should be 2, as two numbers '33333' and '33337' are repeated (it does not matter how many times they are repeated).

I tried

```
grep -Po '(Global)=\K\d+' file.dat | sort | uniq -c
```

but I get the frequency of occurrence of each number, which I don't need:

```
2 33333
1 33334
1 33335
1 33336
3 33337
```

Any help will be appreciated, gre, awk and sed solutions are acceptable.

Comment: 33333 has only one repetition ... 33334 has zero repetitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `uniq -c` to `uniq -d`:

```
$ grep -Po '(Global)=\K\d+' file.dat | sort | uniq -d
33333
33337
```

`-d` prints only duplicated lines. A further pipe to `wc -l` could count those lines. Also note that both `-P` & `-o` options to grep are non-standard, so will not be available in every version of `grep`.

Comment: `-o` is not standard either, both `-o` and `-P` are GNU extensions, though nowadays both can be found in several other implementations (`-o` is more common though, and not `grep` implementations that support `-P` support `\K` in the perl-like regexp)

Comment: If you replace `grep -Po '(Global)=\K\d+'` with `awk 'sub(/Global=/,"")' file` then it'll work anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of numbers that are repeated and eliminate all extra processes:

```
$ awk -F= '$1=="Global"{c[$2]++} END{for (num in c) if(c[num]>1)print num}' file.dat
33333
33337
```

The above code uses `=` as a field separator.  If the first field is `Global`, then we keep track in associative array `c` of the number of times that the second field, `$2`, has appeared in the file.

After the file has been read completely, we look through array `c` and print all numbers which had a count larger than 1.

#### Shorter version

As proposed by [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) in the comments, we could simply print the number on its second appearance:

```
$ awk -F= '++c[$2] == 2 {print $2}' file.dat
33333
33337
```

Comment: This can be more concise: print the num when it seen for the 2nd time: `awk -F= '++c[$2] == 2 {print $2}'` or if we only care about the number of duplicates: `awk -F= '++c[$2] == 2 {dups++} END {print dups}`

Comment: @glennjackman Excellent idea!  I just added print-on-2nd-occurrence to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F'=' '++cnt[$2] == 2{ dups++ } END{print dups+0}' file
2
```

If you do need to check for `Global` then:

```
$ awk -F'=' '($1 == "Global") && (++cnt[$2] == 2){ dups++ } END{print dups+0}' file
2
```

The `+0` in the END is to ensure you get numeric output (`0` instead of a null string) even if there are no dups in the input.